# Creating a Secondary Y-Axis in SSRS

Tags: ssrs-2008, reporting-services

I am trying to create a graph with a primary and secondary y-axis using ssrs 2008 r2.  Looking through the forums, I see that the only suggested answer is using Dundas (www.dundas.com).

I have been able to create a secondary y-axis, but cannot change value type or type of chart.

Can someone point me in the right direction to create a primary y-axis, a secondary y-axis with different values for primary/secondary and change the type of chart between the primary and secondary y-axis.

Comment: [This post](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlreportingservices/thread/ed5f393c-d071-4de8-9df3-f2cdb594517b) seems to report that it is possible in SQL Server 2008.  Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I figured out the solution several hours after creating this post.

Answer (score 3):

Right click on the series value whose chart type you want to change and then select chart type.